# Typescript Index signature with arrays of varying interfaces

Tags: typescript, vuejs3

I am using Typescript with Vue 3, using setup script.
Considering these 3 interfaces:

```
export interface Asset {
    id: number
    name: string
    assetId: string
    assetTypeId: number
    properties?: string[]
}

export interface DynTableField {
    key: string
    col: string
    label: string
}

export interface DynTableItem extends Asset, Group, Location {}
```

I am using the later interface for a Table component that takes in either Asset, Group or Location typed data (i.e. one table component for many scenarios). Because this is a dynamic table I have to calculate the data fields. Part of the code is:

```vue
<tr
   v-for="item in items.data"
   :key="item.id"
>
  <td v-for="field in displayedFields" :key="field.key">
    {{ getField(item, field) }}
  </td>
</tr>
```

Where 'items.data' is an array of type DynTableItem (consider Asset) and the getField function is this:

```
function getField(item: DynTableItem, field: DynTableField): string {
  if (field.col == 'properties' && item.properties) {
    return item.properties[field.key]
  }
  return item[field.key]
}
```

The data typed with Asset has a "properties" field (JSON field in MySQL that gets converted to an array from PHP) and if the loop his that field we read out the property by key, otherwise the table data by key.

Now ... all works fine, except that the linter complains in the "getField" function that "item.properties[field.key]" has an implicit any because the index signature is not of type number.

The "items.data" stems from this interface:

```
export interface Paginator<T> {
    data: T[]
}
```

I DID read some articles on TS index signatures, but I don't see how I can key "items.data" properly. Maybe I am missing something real simple here. But I am not getting my head around it.

Help?

Comment: If `properties` is an array, that means it is indexed by a number by definition. What is an example `key` string? Seems to me `key` should be of type `number`, not `string`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is working version that satisfies eslint as well as produces the right output:

```
function getField(item: DynTableItem, field: DynTableField): string {
  if (field.col === 'properties' && item.properties) {
    //using type guards
    if (Array.isArray(item.properties)) {
      const index = parseInt(field.key, 10)
      const value = item.properties[index]
      return value !== undefined && value !== null ? String(value) : ''
    } else {
      const value = item.properties[field.key]
      return value !== undefined && value !== null ? String(value) : ''
    }
  }
  const value = item[field.key as keyof DynTableItem]
  return value !== undefined && value !== null ? String(value) : ''
}
```

The Asset interface was also amended:

```
export interface Asset {
    id: number
    name: string
    assetId: string
    assetTypeId: number
    properties?: string[] | { [key: string]: string };
}
```